# How to select and transfer specific string values into new column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table of items that can be arranged into groups. The table contains an attribute column with string values, as an example I chose color. For some items, the color column is empty.

| ItemID | Group | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 'blue' |
| 002 | A | 'blue' |
| 003 | A | 'blue' |
| 004 | A | 'blue' |
| 005 | A |  |
| 101 | B | 'red' |
| 102 | B | 'red' |
| 103 | B |  |
| 104 | B |  |
| 105 | B | 'green' |

From this table I want to select only the items that do not have a color assigned yet and display a proposed color in a new column. The proposed color should be taken from the item with the highest ID value within each group.

The desired output should look like this:

| ItemID | Group | Proposed Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 005 | A | 'blue' |
| 103 | B | 'green' |
| 104 | B | 'green' |

I have no idea how to select specific values from the color column based on values from another column (in this case ItemID) and assign them to a different row within my table.
Any help (also keywords describing the concept associated with my problem...) would be greatly appreciated!

(edit) This is what I've tried so far:

```sql
WITH temp_id AS (
SELECT max(ItemID), GroupName
FROM myTable
WHERE Color IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY GroupName
)
SELECT myTable.*, temp_id.*
FROM myTable
JOIN temp_id
ON temp_id.groupName = myTable.groupName;
```

But the output is missing the color column and I wasn't able to add a condition `WHERE Color IS NOT NULL` to my outer selection.

Comment: can you share information regarding the DBMS you're using and your last coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: First, you need to extract the `max(ID)` by group (`GROUP BY`) for row `WHERE` the color is `NOT NULL`.
Next, you need to `JOIN` those to the select of your empty color.

Comment: Thank you @Blag, I've tried following your instructions and I can see it going in the right direction, but I am still missing something to get my desired output. I've edited my initial question and added the code that I've tried.
Sorry in case I was spamming you with notifications because I edited this comment multiple times. This is my first time posting here :)

Comment: Hi @lemon, this is more of an "me trying to understand the SQL concept behind a certain query" problem. Usally I work with an BI tool at my company. But I can't seem to explain this query to our data analysts and architects in a way that they can support my with creating this query in our BI tool. So I figured I just give it a try and break it down to SQL... Was using DB-Fiddle with MySQL v8.0 for this. I added my last coding attempt to my initial question.

Comment: @krausinski not a fan of the WITH, so I gave you the sub query version below, with breakdown per block, hop it'll help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're close, I'll give you the answer, feel free to ask if you don't understand :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/131218/19)

**Query 1**:

```
-- full query 
SELECT mt.itemID, mt.Group, tColor.Color as proposedColor
FROM myTable as mt
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT tMax.Group, tC.Color
  FROM (
    SELECT max(t.ItemID) ItemID, t.Group
    FROM myTable as t
    WHERE t.Color IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY t.Group
    ) tMax
  LEFT JOIN myTable tC
    ON tC.ItemID = tMax.ItemID
  ) tColor
  ON tColor.Group = mt.Group
WHERE mt.Color IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/131218/19/0)**:

```
| itemID | Group | proposedColor |
|--------|-------|---------------|
|      5 |     A |          blue |
|    103 |     B |         green |
|    104 |     B |         green |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- details :
-- 1) the get max id per group 

SELECT max(t.ItemID) ItemID, t.Group
FROM myTable as t
WHERE t.Color IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.Group
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/131218/19/1)**:

```
| ItemID | Group |
|--------|-------|
|      4 |     A |
|    105 |     B |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- 2) the color per group
SELECT tMax.Group, tC.Color
  FROM (
    SELECT max(t.ItemID) ItemID, t.Group
    FROM myTable as t
    WHERE t.Color IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY t.Group
    ) tMax
  LEFT JOIN myTable tC
    ON tC.ItemID = tMax.ItemID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/131218/19/2)**:

```
| Group | Color |
|-------|-------|
|     A |  blue |
|     B | green |
```

**Query 4**:

```
-- 3) the row that need a proposed color
SELECT mt.itemID, mt.Group, null as proposedColor
FROM myTable as mt
-- LEFT JOIN...
WHERE mt.Color IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/131218/19/3)**:

```
| itemID | Group | proposedColor |
|--------|-------|---------------|
|      5 |     A |        (null) |
|    103 |     B |        (null) |
|    104 |     B |        (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Blag! I really appreciate the structured breakdown of the query, helped me a lot with understanding this better. Now, I also managed to solve this with my initial query using a `WITH` clause. Can you tell me though why you think it is better to use this nested approach rather than a `WITH` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join again with myTable in order to get the Color of the MaxID you calculated in the temp_id table:

```
WITH temp_id AS (
SELECT max(ItemID) AS MaxId, GroupName
FROM myTable
WHERE Color IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY GroupName
)
SELECT myTable.*, T2.Color
FROM myTable
JOIN temp_id
ON temp_id.groupName = myTable.groupName
JOIN myTable T2
ON T2.ItemID = temp_id.MaxID;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d550baeb248efc3b846493656a1110f3).

Answer (score 0):

This could work as well:

```
WITH test_data AS
(
  SELECT '001' AS "item_id", 'A' AS "group", 'blue' AS "color" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '002', 'A', 'blue'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '003', 'A', 'blue'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '004', 'A', 'blue'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '005', 'A', NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '101', 'B', 'red'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '102', 'B', 'red'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '103', 'B', NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '104', 'B', NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '105', 'B', 'green' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT items."item_id", items."group", colors."proposed color"
  FROM (SELECT td."group", MIN(td."color") AS "proposed color"
          FROM test_data td
         GROUP BY td."group") colors
         INNER JOIN (SELECT td."item_id", td."group"
                       FROM test_data td
                      WHERE td."color" IS NULL) items
            ON items."group" = colors."group"
 ORDER BY items."item_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MAX` window function to retrieve the value of "*Color*" with respect to each ItemID, then get the rows that had "*Color*" assigned null:

```
SELECT ItemID,
       Group_,
       MaxColor AS Color
FROM (SELECT *,
             MAX(Color) OVER(
                 PARTITION BY Group_ 
                 ORDER     BY CAST(ItemID AS UNSIGNED)) AS MaxColor
      FROM tab) cte
WHERE Color IS NULL
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hVB6BevVsT93aACbsZvnZF/0).

**Note**: If you don't care about selecting only those specific rows with NULL values, you can just use the window function as follows.

```
SELECT ItemID,
       Group,
       COALESCE(Color, MAX(Color) OVER(
                           PARTITION BY Group
                           ORDER     BY CAST(ItemID AS UNSIGNED))) AS Color
FROM tab
```

The `COALESCE` function will give priority to the Color field, and when it is null, it will catch the `MAX` window function output.